# how to write or append data into a file that already exist in s3 bucket with python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am have a text file with name pythonpoc in s3 bucket. Now i want to append some more data into that text file. How can I do that without using lambda function.

Comment: Appending data to an S3 object is not possible, regardless of how you try to do it (with Lambda or otherwise). You would need to read the object, append your new content to the existing content, then replace the entire S3 object.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to append data to a file that already exist in S3 then it is not directly supported by S3.

However, what you can do is that read the file and the append that data locally to that and then write the file back to S3 with the same path/key. You can do that from AWS Lambda or anywhere else using AWS SDK.

However when you do that keep in mind the Eventual Consistency drawback of S3. You can read more about [Eventual Consistency here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html)

> **Amazon S3 Data Consistency Model**
>
> Amazon S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new
>   objects in your S3 bucket in all regions with one caveat. The caveat
>   is that if you make a HEAD or GET request to the key name (to find if
>   the object exists) before creating the object, Amazon S3 provides
>   eventual consistency for read-after-write.
>
> Amazon S3 offers eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES
>   in all regions.
>
> Updates to a single key are atomic. For example, if you PUT to an
>   existing key, a subsequent read might return the old data or the
>   updated data, but it will never return corrupted or partial data.